# Trouble loading php result into div using jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Good Morning,
Let me apologize in advance for troubling this community with my issue; as I am the novice of novices at best when it comes to any kind of development, and I feel I'm lucky to have made it this far before hitting a roadblock lol.

I've been putting together a simple internal application for our company, and the problem I'm dealing with now happens to be the final piece of the puzzle.  What I'm trying to do is use the jQuery load() method to display the output of "index2.php", within the "test" div identified on my main page.

I need the result to print out on my main page, because I've failed miserably at getting the page to work using iframes.  My objective - when a user enters a search term in the text box then clicks the submit button; index2.php connects with and queries a mysql db, and prints the query result into the "test" div as a table.

My current code does't pull the php result into the div when the submit button is clicked; it just sits there without any change, and no errors or any activity in the console.  During my wild and frantic searches; I've tried out several other methods such as using 'after()' in place of 'load()', which merely displayed the text "index2.php" on my page instead of the table output.

I know the 'after()' method isn't going to give me the result I'm looking for, but it did appear to give confirmation that the rest of my code is correct...I think lol.  I apologize again for any obvious faux-pas you may find, being a true dyed in the wool amateur at this.  That being said, thank you very much for any help or insight anyone is willing to provide! :)

Here's my code:

Contents of `Index.html`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <html><head>
        <title>My page</title>

        <!--calls jquery, applys stylesheet-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>
    <br>

    <header><h5><center><font size="22">My Page<font size="4">®</font></font></center></h5></header>

        <!--Search box and submit button, querying db and displaying results of index2.php-->

    <center><div>
    <br>
        <form id="index2" action="" method="POST" target="test" />
            <input type="text" name="sb" id="searchBox" placeholder="" value="" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" onmousedown="" onblur="" />
            <input type="button" id="searchBtn" value="Submit" />
    </form></div>
    </center>
    <br>
            <!--This is where the "index2.php search results should be displayed-->

    <center><div id="test"></div></center>
    <br>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        //-This is the jQuery load() method to call the "index2.php" results into the "test" div when submit is clicked-//

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('searchBtn').click(function(){
            $('#test').load('<object data=index2.php>')
//-I've tried using simply .load('index2.php') and .load('/index2.php') here as well-//
            });
        });
    </script>
    </html>
```

And here's the code for `index2.php`:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["sb"])) {
    echo '';
} else {
    $db_host = 'some.host';
    $db_user = 'user';
    $db_pwd = 'password';
    $database = 'database_name';
    $table = 'calls';
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result) . " Results for: " . $_GET["sb"];
    $sb = $_GET["sb"];
    $q = 1;
    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to database" . mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, $database)) {
        die("Can't select database");
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `calls` FROM `calls` WHERE calls LIKE '%$sb%' LIMIT 25");
    if (!$result) {
        die("Query to show fields from table failed");
    }
    $fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    echo "<table border='1'><br><br>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        if ($q % 2 != 0) {
            $rowColor = "#dddddd";
        } else {
            $rowColor = "#FFFFFF";
        }
        echo "<tr bgcolor = $rowColor>";
        $q++;
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><a href='/calls/$cell' id='callpath'>Play Now</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to read all your code, you don't use indentation?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/  Check out the documentation.  Your syntax of <object data=index2.php> seems odd.  I would anticipate seeing load('index2.php')

Comment: Hi Pedro! thanks for the quick response!  Not sure why the code isn't showing, could be because I was editting my post?  I used ctrl+k to identify the code.  In my edit I responded to your suggestion, I have tried referring to index2.php several different ways within the js, such as .load('index2.php') and .load('/index2.php').  And I forgot to mention that the file is sitting at the root as well.

Comment: If you load index2.php directly in your browser, does it render the code correctly?

Comment: Also, your code requires a $_GET['sb'] or it will return nothing .load('/index2.php?sb=SOMEVALUE')

Comment: Sorry still getting the hang of this place lol, seem to be responding in the wrong place for each comment.  Regarding your inquiry about index2.php, yes it does work if accessed directly.  As I mentioned in another response, it prints the queried table correctly when I used a targetted iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your code:

1. the start tag in your form does not need an ending slash: like `<form />`
2. jQuery needs a hash to look for the id, missing hash: `$('searchBtn')`
3. Youre not submitting your form correctly. If im not mistaken, youre trying to pass whatever you type in as a query string, but youre currently not passing anything.
4. `load()` looks for a URL, no need to use object. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Do it in this manner:

```
<form id="index2_form">
    <input type="text" name="sb" id="searchBox" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    $('#index2_form').submit(function () {
        var query = $(this).serialize();
        var url = "index2.php?" + query;
        $('#test').load(url);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

.load() takes an url as argument and places the returned HTML into the matched element. try this:

```
$('#test').load('path/to/your/index2.php?sb=searchterm')
```

edit:
you would also have to pass the value of your search-input to index2.php

Comment: thanks for your response jbe, but index2.php actually sits in the root folder, and I've tried using both with and without the /

Comment: Isn't that obtained from within the php document?  the contents of the textbox is identified as 'sb' which is what the query uses as a variable when searching.

Comment: because index2.php returns an empty string, if `$_GET['sb']` is empty.

Comment: I use the term 'test' when I click submit. The function of index2.php and the form I've used works properly when I had it setup to display the output within an iframe...but the iframe screwed up the other purpose of the site

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#searchBtn').click(function () {
        let searchTerm = $('#searchBox').text();
        $('#test').load("index2.php?sb=" + searchTerm);
    });
</script>
```

I made the above modification showing how you might get the search term into your query.

Comment: Thank you!  Before I test this out, would I need to change the form from POST to GET so the query is reflected in the url?

Comment: According to the console, when I click the submit button, I see it pass the full url including the "?sb=test" term as well, but nothing happens on the page.  no errors either